# How to create a docker image from layers and manifest? Once assembled into an image, how do I spawn a container out of it?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

I have the layer files and the manifest available, what else do I need to create a docker image out of it? The image should be loadable and should allow spawning of a docker container.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about how you got these pieces, separately from a normal `docker pull`/`docker run` sequence?

Comment: @DavidMaze : I used docker registry's http api's to get the manifest and the layer files.                                                                                                                           
 For Manifest : GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>                                                              For Layers : GET /v2/<name>/blobs/<digest>                                                                     I have them into a tar package which looks like an official image, but when I try to execute a docker run on this tar package, I get "No command specified error"